# LocationServices.SettingsApi calling onActivityResult with RESULT_CANCELED?

Tags: android, android-activity, gps, onactivityresult

I have been struggling with new LocationServices.SettingsApi in one particular case.
I have written code on SplashActivity for Location setting(Google GPS Dialog Box which turn on GPS automatically) its run perfectly on Lollipop but in lower version like Kitkat or Jelly Bean its  not showing google dialog box its showing RESULT_CANCELED in onActivityResult.. :(

PFA
Google Dialog Box Image
Code Snippet[Google Dialog Box for automatically turning GPS on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FiPoD.jpg)

```
if(googleApiClient == null) {

        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(MapsActivity.this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).build();
        googleApiClient.connect();

        LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        locationRequest.setInterval(30 * 1000);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5 * 1000);
        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                .addLocationRequest(locationRequest);

        //**************************
        builder.setAlwaysShow(true); //this is the key ingredient
        //**************************

        PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result =
                LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(googleApiClient, builder.build());
        result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult result) {
                final Status status = result.getStatus();
                final LocationSettingsStates state = result.getLocationSettingsStates();
                switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                        // All location settings are satisfied. The client can initialize location
                        // requests here.
                        break;
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                        // Location settings are not satisfied. But could be fixed by showing the user
                        // a dialog.
                        try {
                            // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                            // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                            status.startResolutionForResult(
                                   MapsActivity.this, 1000);
                        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                            // Ignore the error.
                        }
                        break;
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                        // Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no way to fix the
                        // settings so we won't show the dialog.
                        break;
                }
            }
        });             }
```

the above code is for automatically turning gps on

and below code is of onActivityResult

```
@Override

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    LatLng currentLoc = LocationProvider.currentLoc;

    switch (resultCode) {
        case Activity.RESULT_OK:
            mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);
            if(mLastLocation!=null)
            {
                currentLoc = new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude());
            }

            Log.e(TAG, "RESULT OK");
            break;
        case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
            checkGPSstatus();
            Log.e(TAG, "RESULT_CANCELED");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's try to guess. Do you have `launchMode` set to `singleInstance` for your activity? If so, you are not allowing other activities to be part of your task.

Answer (score 0):

Please re-take a look at this project on `Github`:

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location

You can try to re-write your code following one of those examples because it works in `KitKat` and `JellyBean` as well as `Lollipop`.

I have already implemented it a few days ago and is working in this way.